# Latest Rep Changes

Tags: feature-request

The Reputation tab on the user page is great, except it orders it in amounts of reputation, is there a way to order it in date order? That way you can see why you reputation just went up and if you need to do something.

Comment: It seems to already sort by date

Comment: Where are you looking? My profile certainly doesn't (http://stackoverflow.com/users/191463/jonathan?tab=reputation)

Comment: Oh, I thought you meant the tab on the recent activity page; see [Rebecca's answer](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/79103/latest-rep-changes/79106#79106)

Comment: @Micheal I never even seen those tabs :) Confusing how it's seperated from the other rep tab. on the surface SO is pretty basic and easy to use, but once you get into it there's a load more functionality :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want something within the last month or so, click the envelope next to your name at the top and go to the reputation tab.  You can select the date range you prefer.

https://stackoverflow.com/users/recent/191463?Tab=Reputation&StartDate=2011-02-12&EndDate=2011-02-12

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way to see the most recent changes is to select the far-right area of the graph.

[image: screenshot]

Alternatively, the reputation change data [returned by the API](http://api.stackoverflow.com/1.0/users/191463/reputation?type=jsontext) seems to be oreder by date.

Comment: I know about the API, I've been using that for a while now, but's not very easy to read as a simple list. Selecting the far right, narrows it down but still doesn't give in date order, which is annoying if you have got a lot of seperate rep changes in the minimum space.